# Dart native extension : asynchronous but blocking?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, dart-native-extension

After some try, it's that I can see :
The extension execution is asynchronous from dart but not C, which is blocking while the current method has not completed.

```dart
Dart_NativeFunction ResolveName(Dart_Handle name, int argc);
Dart_Handle HandleError(Dart_Handle handle);

void wrapped_method(Dart_Port dest_port_id, Dart_CObject* message) {
  Dart_Port reply_port_id = message->value.as_array.values[0]->value.as_send_port;

  printf("Before sleep\n");
  sleep(5);

  printf("Hello from c !\n");

  Dart_CObject result;
  result.type = Dart_CObject_kBool;
  result.value.as_bool = true;
  Dart_PostCObject(reply_port_id, &result);
}

DART_EXPORT Dart_Handle sample_extension_Init(Dart_Handle parent_library) {                  
  if (Dart_IsError(parent_library)) { return parent_library; }                         
  Dart_Handle result_code = Dart_SetNativeResolver(parent_library, ResolveName);       
    if (Dart_IsError(result_code)) return result_code;                                 
    return Dart_Null();                                                                
}


void sample_extension_ServicePort(Dart_NativeArguments arguments) {                          
  Dart_EnterScope();                                                                   
  Dart_SetReturnValue(arguments, Dart_Null());                                         
  Dart_Port service_port = Dart_NewNativePort("sample_extension_ServicePort",     wrapped_method, true); 
  if (service_port != ILLEGAL_PORT) {                                                  
    Dart_Handle send_port = HandleError(Dart_NewSendPort(service_port));               
    Dart_SetReturnValue(arguments, send_port);                                         
  }                                                                                    
  Dart_ExitScope();                                                                    
}  

struct FunctionLookup {
  const char* name;
  Dart_NativeFunction function;
};

FunctionLookup function_list[] = {
    {"SampleExtension_ServicePort", sample_extension_ServicePort},
    {NULL, NULL}};

Dart_NativeFunction ResolveName(Dart_Handle name, int argc) {                        
  if (!Dart_IsString(name)) return NULL;                                               
  Dart_NativeFunction result = NULL;                                                   
  Dart_EnterScope();                                                                   
  const char* cname;                                                                   
  HandleError(Dart_StringToCString(name, &cname));                                     
  for (int i=0; function_list[i].name != NULL; ++i) {
    if (strcmp(function_list[i].name, cname) == 0) {
      result = function_list[i].function;
      break;
    }
  }
  Dart_ExitScope();                                                                    
  return result;                                                                       
}                                                                                      

Dart_Handle HandleError(Dart_Handle handle) {                                          
  if (Dart_IsError(handle)) Dart_PropagateError(handle);                               
  return handle;                                                                       
}
```

When I execute 3 times a method calling the service port :

```
Hello from Dart
Hello from Dart
Before sleep
Hello from Dart
Hello from c !
Before sleep
Hello from c !
Before sleep
Hello from c !
```

Until every "Hello from c!", its sleep 5 seconds.
There is a way to be also asynchronous in the C side ?
I have seen :

```dart
DART_EXPORT Dart_Port Dart_NewNativePort(const char* name,
                                     Dart_NativeMessageHandler handler,
                                     bool handle_concurrently);
```

Great ! But ...

```dart
/* TODO(turnidge): Currently handle_concurrently is ignored. */
```

Is there a issue about that ? (I want to vote for it to follow solutions)
While the issue is not fixed, what is the best solution ?
Running code in a C fork ?